# Alexa Skill : How to accept response while alexa speechout continuing

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

**UseCase - Quiz skill**:  Alexa ask a question with 30 sec (Countdown).

For Countdown, I followed [How to make Alexa countdown in seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388933/how-to-make-alexa-countdown-in-seconds)

**Problem**:  While Countdown going one if the user responded with an answer. Alexa instead of accepting the response it continues with count down. Alexa accepting response only after countdown.

```
My speech out/speak from Alexa looks like this:  Sam Your Question Nobody enjoys this feat? Your time start now 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.  The countdown code you are using outputs speech for the duration of the countdown.  You can't "open the microphone" during the speech output (no blue ring).  The microphone will open for the user's response for [eight seconds](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-design/available.html#design-for-response-time-limits) only after the speech output is complete, and you have prompted the user for input.

Your best bet is to either do your count-down speech or play a short "thinking" MP3 clip (think something Jeopardy-like) for a fixed amount of time and then prompt the user for the answer.  Something like "10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.  Time's up!  What's your answer?"

Answer (score 0):

While countdown going if you want Alexa to accept your answer then you will have to speak out the wake word "Alexa". The wake word is the only way to open the mic whenever you want and stop the countdown. So say "Alexa", and then give your response. This will work